# Java JsonParseException: Unexpected character Reading JSON from Oracle 11g

Tags: java, json, oracle11g, jackson, deserialization

We have some data that is being saved in a CLOB column in Oracle 11g as serialized JSON. Later this data is read back and deserialized. However in some cases the deserialization is failing (using Jackson).

```
 Failed to deserialize emvData JSON into HashMap. EMVData -> weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB@1e52cd
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('w' (code 119)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@56c70524; line: 1, column: 2]
```

The thing is there isn't a 'w' character anywhere in the JSON it tried to deserialize. I am suspecting it may be a character encoding issue... The Oracle 11g server is using AL32UTF8.

This is the code that is doing the serialization:

```
public String serializeEMVData(Map<String, String> emvData) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if (emvData != null) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(emvData);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to serialize EMV data as JSON", ex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is the code doing the deserialization

```
public static Map<String, String> deserializeEMVData(String serializedEmvData) {


        HashMap<String, String> emvData = null;
        if (serializedEmvData != null) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                emvData = objectMapper.readValue(serializedEmvData, HashMap.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Failed to deserialize emvData JSON into HashMap. EMVData -> " + serializedEmvData.toString(), e);
            }
        }
        if (emvData != null) {
            return new TreeMap<String, String>(emvData);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I tell Java the character set is AL32UTF8 or do I need to convert it in the query....

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting the CLOB to String properly?
Looks like you're trying to convert CLOB.toString() (i.e "weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Clob_oracle_sql_CLOB@1e52cd") to java object.